# Problem with User Registration

Tags: php, mysql, forms, registration

For some reason my script keeps saying "Please enter your passwords" and try again and never actually finishes. Any clues? Here is my code:(I put EXAMPLE where my website name is:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){

        $trimmed = array_map('trim', $_POST);

        $fn = $ln = $e = $p = FALSE;


        //First Name
        if (preg_match ('/^[A-Z \'.-]{2,20}$/i',$trimmed['first_name'])) {

            $fn = mysql_real_escape_string($trimmed['first_name']);
            $trimmed['first_name'];
        } else {

            echo "<p class='error'>Please Enter Your First Name</p>";
        }


        //Last Name
        if (preg_match ('/^[A-Z \'.-]{2,40}$/i',$trimmed['last_name'])) {

            $ln = mysql_real_escape_string($trimmed['last_name']);
            $trimmed['last_name'];
        } else {

            echo "<p class='error'>Please Enter Your Last Name</p>";
        }



        //Check for an email address
        if(preg_match ('/^[\w.-]+@[\w.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}$/', $trimmed['email'])) {
            $e = mysql_real_escape_string($trimmed['email']);
        } else{
            echo "<p class='error'>Please Enter a Valid Email Address</p>";
        }

        //Password

        if (preg_match ('/^\w{4,20}$/',$trimmed['password1'])){
            if ($trimmed['password1'] == $trimmed['password2']) {
                $p = mysql_real_escape_string($trimmed['password1']);

            } else{
                echo "<p class='error'>Your Password did not match the confirmed password</p>";
            }
        } else{
            echo "<p class='error'>Please enter a valid Password</p>";
        }

        if($n && $ln && $e && $p) {
            $q = "SELECT user_id from users WHERE email='$e'";
            $r = mysql_query($link,$q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysql_error($link));
            if (mysql_num_rows($r) == 0){
                $a = md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
                $q = "INSERT INTO users (email, pass, first_name, last_name, active, registration_date) VALUES ('$e', SHA1('$p'), '$fn', '$ln', '$a', NOW() )";
                $r= mysql_query ($link, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysql_error($link));

                if(mysql_affected_rows($link) == 1){
                    $body = "Thank you for signing up for a Example Account. To activate your account, please click on this link:\n\n";
                    $body .= BASE_URL . 'activate.php?x=' . urlencode($e) . "&y=$a";

                    mail($trimmed['email'], 'Example Account Confirmation', $body, 'From: support@example.com');
                    echo"<h3>Thank You for Signing Up. A confirmation email has been sent to your email. Please click on the link we sent you to activate your account.</h3>";
                    exit();
                } else{
                    echo "<p class='error'>You could not be registered due to a system error. We apologize for any inconvenience.</p>";
                }
            } else {
                echo "<p class='error'>That email address has already been registered. If you have forgotten your password, please visit: <a href='./forgot.php'>Forgot Your Password?</a></p>";
            }

        } else{
            echo"<p class='error'>Please re-enter your passwords and try again.</p>";
        }
    mysql_close($link);
    }
    ?>
    <form action='signup.php' method='post'>
            <p><b>First Name:<br/></b><input type='text' name='first_name' size='20' maxlength='20' value='<?php if (isset($trimmed['first_name'])) { echo $trimmed['first_name'];} ?>'></p><br/>
            <p><b>Last Name:<br/></b><input type='text' name='last_name' size='20' maxlength='40' value='<?php if (isset($trimmed['last_name'])) { echo $trimmed['last_name'];} ?>'></p><br/>
            <p><b>Email<br/></b><input type='text' name='email' size='30' maxlength='80' value='<?php if (isset($trimmed['email'])) { echo $trimmed['email'];} ?>'></p><br/>
            <p><b>Password<br/></b><input type='password' name='password1' size='20' maxlength='20' /><small> Use only letters, numbers, and underscores. Must be between 4-20 Characters Long.</small></p><br/>
            <p><b>Confirm Password<br/></b><input type='password' name='password2' size='20' maxlength='20' /></p><br/>
            <input type='hidden' name='submitted' value='true'/>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Sign Up!'/>
    </form>
```

Comment: have you tried debugging the array $trimmed to see whats in there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy.  `$fn = mysql_real_escape_string($trimmed['first_name']);` `if($n && $ln && $e && $p)`  You're checking `$n` instead of `$fn`, or setting `$n` instead of `$fn`, depending on how you look at it.

Comment: This is why people should not turn off notices... And use more meaningful variable names.

Comment: I just did that and now got 3 warnings and 5 notices about lines 67 and 70...Is there anything else in there that is wrong?

Comment: Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /Users/Jacob/Sites/gj/signup.php on line 66

Notice: Query: SELECT user_id from users WHERE email='EMAIL' 
MySQL Error: in /Users/Jacob/Sites/gj/signup.php on line 66

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in /Users/Jacob/Sites/gj/signup.php on line 67

Comment: Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in /Users/Jacob/Sites/gj/signup.php on line 70
Notice: Query: INSERT INTO users (email, pass, first_name, last_name, active, registration_date) VALUES ('EMAIL', SHA1('admin'), 'NAME', 'NAME', '57af999b5fc9d93d6f4229ba3982fa29', NOW()) 
MySQL Error: in /Users/Jacob/Sites/gj/signup.php on line 70

Comment: thanks for your help. I am trying to learn php out of this book and I'm not really sure what happened but i got a lot of errors.

Comment: Ah, I see one error `$r = mysql_query($link,$q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysql_error($link));`, you're passing the dsn first for the mysql_query, needs to be `$r = mysql_query($q,$link)`  Same for the second query before the mail gets sent.  Hence "mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be a string" so mysql_num_rows doesn't have a valid mysql result resource because the query never happens.